# Update ajax content with will_paginate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

How can I update my view keeping all existing ajax and will_paginate functionality in place?

I have a page `rehome.html.erb`

```
<div id="options">Option Select Here</>

<div class="all_animals">
  <%= render @animals %>
</div>

<% unless @animals.current_page == @animals.total_pages %>
  <div id="infinite-scrolling">
    <%= will_paginate @animals %>
  </div>
<% end %>

// WILL_PAGINATE
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

 if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    //Bail out right away if we're busy loading the next chunk
     if(window.pagination_loading){
        return;
     }

    more_url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');

  if(more_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50){
    //Make a note that we're busy loading the next chunk.
     window.pagination_loading = true;
    $('.pagination').text('Loading.....');
       $.getScript(more_url).always(function(){
          window.pagination_loading = false;
       });
    }
  });
 }
});
</script>
```

This will load all the @animals collection, paginating it to 6 per page, and when I scroll down the page another 6 are loaded etc etc.

Corresponding controller

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :default_animal, only: [:rehome]

 def rehome
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end

private

def default_animal
 @animals = Animal.animals_rehome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end

end
```

rehome.js.erb

```
$('.all_animals').append('<%= j render @animals %>');
 <% if @animals.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
<% else %>
 $(window).off('scroll');
 $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

So when an option is selected from the dropdown an ajax post is made to create a new query which will return a new collection of @animals

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/public/rehomed',
  data: data_send,
   success: function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Controller

```
def rehomed
# conditions logic
@animals = Animal.joins(:user).where(conditions).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render json: @animals }
 end
end
```

What I want to do is have the new collection loaded (paginated to 6 per page again) and when I scroll down only show the objects belonging to the new collection of @animals (if there are any).

At the moment the pagination links are not updated as when I scroll down the page the original collection is loaded.

### Edit

So I have created a `rehomed.js.erb` file which is pretty much the same as my `rehome.js.erb`:

```
$('.all_animals').empty();
$('.all_animals').append('<%= j render @animals %>');
 <% if @animals.next_page %>
   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @animals %>');
 <% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
 <% end %>
```

and within my rehomed action

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
end
```

So the new collection of animals is loaded, the pagination links are recreated but using the rehomed url, example being:

## Before

```
<a class="next_page" href="/public/rehome?page=2" rel="next">Next →</a>
```

## After

```
<a class="next_page" href="/public/rehomed?page=2" rel="next">Next →</a>
```

So when I scroll down I just get the following as the links don't exist and getScript fails

```
$('.pagination').text('Loading.....');
```

### Edit 2

I have implemented @japed's answer but now after the new collection is rendered the pagination will continue to render the whole collection of the db including repeating the ones that where selected for the new collection, it's repeating itself.

How can I ensure that the correct url is generated for my links?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your problem is.  You just want an onclick on your select or an onchange event binder

Comment: @japed apologies, i have updated my question which will hopefully explain things further

Answer (score 2):

Will paginate allows you to set the params hash so you should be able to change it to use your other controller action like this:

```
will_paginate(@animals, :params => { :controller => "public", :action => "rehomed" })
```

Comment: thanks, that does solve my issue of setting the correct links which is great, but for some reason now once i get to the end of the new collection of results it just carries on and then loads all the records left in the entire db